# Can anyone please shorten this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]This query generates next datafile name for a existing schema.
For e.g. id last datafile name is test_schema_05.dbf
then this query gives test_schema_06.dbf
I need to shorten this query .

Is this possible?

```
SELECT  CONCAT
    (SUBSTR
        (MAX
            (SUBSTR 
                (file_name,
                INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                )
            ),
            1,
            INSTR 
                (MAX 
                    (SUBSTR 
                        (file_name, 
                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                        )
                    ),
                    '_',
                    1,
                    (LENGTH 
                        (MAX 
                            (SUBSTR 
                                (file_name, 
                                INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                                )
                            )
                        ) - LENGTH
                            (REPLACE
                                (MAX
                                    (SUBSTR
                                        (file_name, 
                                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    '_'
                                )
                            )
                    )
                )
        ),
        CONCAT
            ('0', 
            SUBSTR
                (MAX 
                    (SUBSTR 
                        (file_name, 
                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1
                        )
                    ),
                    INSTR
                        (MAX 
                            (SUBSTR 
                                (file_name,
                                INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1
                                )
                            ),
                            '_',
                            1,
                            (LENGTH
                                (MAX
                                    (SUBSTR
                                        (file_name,
                                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                                        )
                                    )
                                ) - LENGTH
                                    (REPLACE
                                        (MAX
                                            (SUBSTR
                                                (file_name,
                                                INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            '_'
                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                        ) + 1,
                        INSTR 
                            (MAX 
                                (SUBSTR 
                                    (file_name,
                                    INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1
                                    )
                                ),
                                '.',
                                1
                            ) - INSTR
                                (MAX 
                                    (SUBSTR 
                                        (file_name, 
                                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    '_',
                                    1,
                                    (LENGTH
                                        (MAX
                                            (SUBSTR
                                                (file_name,
                                                INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1
                                                )
                                            )
                                        ) - LENGTH
                                            (REPLACE
                                                (MAX
                                                    (SUBSTR
                                                        (file_name,
                                                        INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1
                                                        )
                                                    ),
                                                    '_'
                                                )
                                            )
                                    )
                                ) - 1
                ) + 1
            )
    )

|| '.dbf'   AS  data_file_name
FROM    dba_data_files
WHERE   tablespace_name = 
    (SELECT     default_tablespace
    FROM        dba_users
    WHERE       username = 'schema_name'
    );
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve by shortening? Readability, Performance, Simlifying the logic?

Comment: You appear to use a fairly complex subtring calculation many times (although I would hope that MySQL will optimise it out to only perform once). For readability you could do this in a sub query.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: i want to shorten it in terms of lines of code

Answer (score 0):

this almost made me cry.  Also, it looks like your query is just somewhat wrong, as your MAX functions appear to only contain a single value, which is a string

You have SO MANY repeated lines that are clogging up your query, and your brain when you try to read it.  Extract that out to a variable!  Assuming this is all inside a sproc somewhere, you end up with something like this:

```
DECLARE i_intLocation   INTEGER;
SET i_intLocation = INSTR (file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/'))) + 1;

DECLARE i_strSubstr     VARCHAR;
SET i_strSubstr = (SUBSTR (file_name, i_intLocation));

SELECT  
CONCAT(
    SUBSTR(
        MAX(i_strSubstr),
        1,
        INSTR(
            MAX(i_strSubstr),
            '_',
            1,
            (
                LENGTH(MAX(i_strSubstr)) 
                - LENGTH(
                    REPLACE(
                        MAX(i_strSubstr),
                        '_'
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    CONCAT(
        '0', 
        SUBSTR(
            MAX(i_strSubstr),
            INSTR(
                MAX(i_strSubstr),
                '_',
                1,
                (
                    LENGTH(MAX(i_strSubstr))
                    - LENGTH(
                        REPLACE(
                            MAX(i_strSubstr),
                            '_'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) + 1,
            INSTR(
                MAX(i_strSubstr),
                '.',
                1
            ) 
            - INSTR(
                MAX(i_strSubstr),
                '_',
                1,
                (
                    LENGTH(MAX(i_strSubstr))
                    - LENGTH(
                        REPLACE(
                            MAX(i_strSubstr),
                            '_'
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) - 1
        ) + 1
    )
)

|| '.dbf'   AS  data_file_name
FROM    dba_data_files
WHERE   tablespace_name = 
    (SELECT     default_tablespace
    FROM        dba_users
    WHERE       username = 'schema_name'
    );
```

Comment: Uhl thanks.  As stated above,this functions gives the highest datafile name for a particular schema and this function works fine for me.I was trying if i could shorten the code a bit more.

Comment: @saurabhk well, if it works, then it works.  Hopefully I didn't screw up when I did the shortening.  I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but now at least it is slightly more readable

Answer (score 0):

Using a sub query to get the highest file name to shorten the code it would come out something like this, but I suspect that this is no more efficient (and might well be less efficient).

```
SELECT    CONCAT(SUBSTR(sub1.derived_bit,1,INSTR(sub1.derived_bit,'_',1,(LENGTH(sub1.derived_bit)- LENGTH(REPLACE(sub1.derived_bit,'_'))))),
CONCAT('0',SUBSTR(sub1.derived_bit,INSTR(sub1.derived_bit,'_',1,(LENGTH(sub1.derived_bit)- LENGTH(REPLACE(sub1.derived_bit,'_'))))+ 1,INSTR
(sub1.derived_bit,'.',1)- INSTR(sub1.derived_bit,'_',1,(LENGTH(sub1.derived_bit)- LENGTH(REPLACE(sub1.derived_bit, '_' ))))- 1)+ 1), '.dbf') AS data_file_name
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(SUBSTR(file_name, INSTR(file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH(file_name) - LENGTH(REPLACE(file_name, '/'))) + 1)) as derived_bit
    FROM dba_data_files 
    INNER JOIN dba_users
    ON dba_data_files.tablespace_name = dba_users.default_tablespace AND username = 'schema_name'
) sub1
```

However this is just based on your code which has syntax errors (which I have just repeated in my code above). For example your code is using INSTR with 4 parameters (should only have 2). Similarly you are using REPLACE with only 2 parameters. Your functions are looking for '/' while the file names you give as example do not contain any '/' characters.

How fixed is the format of the file name? Is there only ever 1 . in the file name? Is the number to increment always immediatly before the .dbf?

Comment: As stated above,this functions gives the highest datafile name for a particular schema and this function works fine for me.I was trying if i could shorten the code a bit more.

Comment: The code you have pasted can't work as the functions in it have the wrong number of parameters. For example a fragment of it is `MAX(SUBSTR(file_name,INSTR(file_name, '/', 1, LENGTH (file_name) - LENGTH (REPLACE (file_name, '/' ))) + 1))` . INSTR here has 4 parameters (it only takes 2) while SUBSTR only has 2. However to shorten the code usefully I need to know more details of exactly what you are trying to shorten, and how you it broken down to shorten it.